# How to change color of circle when collision detection occurs?

Tags: javascript, web, collision-detection, game-physics

As far as I understood it seems that even after changing the color when the collision is detected it reverts back to blue due to the else statement when it is compared between other circle and they are not colliding. So how would you solve this so that that the instance when the collision between any circle occurs it changes to red

collision detection

```js
this.update = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (this !== circles[i] && getDistance(this.x, this.y, circles[i].x, circles[i].y) <= 200 * 200) {
            this.c = 'red';
            circles[i].c = 'red';
            resolveCollision(this, circles[i]);
        } else {
            this.c = 'blue';
            circles[i].c = 'blue';
        }

    }
    //wall deflection
    if (this.x - this.r <= 0 || this.x + this.r >= innerWidth)
        this.v.x *= -1
    if (this.y - this.r <= 0 || this.y + this.r >= innerHeight)
        this.v.y *= -1
    this.x += this.v.x;
    this.y += this.v.y;
    this.draw();
};
//deflection amongst other circles

function resolveCollision(circle, othercircle) {
    const xVelocityDiff = circle.v.x - othercircle.v.x;
    const yVelocityDiff = circle.v.y - othercircle.v.y;
    const xDist = othercircle.x - circle.x;
    const yDist = othercircle.y - circle.y;
    if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0) {
        const angle = -Math.atan2(othercircle.y - circle.y, othercircle.x - circle.x);
        const m1 = circle.m;
        const m2 = othercircle.m;

        const u1 = rotate(circle.v, angle);
        const u2 = rotate(othercircle.v, angle);

        const v1 = {
            x: u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            y: u1.y
        }
        const v2 = {
            x: u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            y: u2.y
        }

        const vFinal1 = rotate(v1, -angle);
        const vFinal2 = rotate(v2, -angle);

        circle.v.x = vFinal1.x;
        circle.v.y = vFinal1.y;
        othercircle.v.x = vFinal2.x;
        othercircle.v.y = vFinal2.y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection#Circle_Collision

Comment: @Bren appreciate it.but i think the problem in my code is the color of the circle object does not appear red when it collide since it gets reverted back to blue when compared with other non colliding circles due to the else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Semaphores

Use a semaphore that holds the collision state of the circle.

Thus in your `Circle.prototype` would have something like these functions and properties

```
Circle.prototype = {
    collided: false,  // when true change color
    draw() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.collided ? "red" : "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r - 1.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
    },

    ...
    ...
    // in update 
    update() {

        // when collision is detected set semaphore
        if (collision) {
            this.collided = true;
        }

    }
}
```

### Counters

Or you may want to only have the color change last for some time. You can modify the semaphore and use it as a counter. On collision set it to the number of frames to change color for.

```
Circle.prototype = {
    collided: 0,
    draw() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.collided ? (this.collided--, "red") : "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r - 1.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
    },

    ...
    ...
    // in update 
    update() {

        // when collision is detected set semaphore
        if (collision) {
            this.collided = 60;  // 1 second at 60FPS
        }

    }
}
```

### Example

This example is taken from another answer I did earlier this year.

As there is a lot of code I have highlighted the relevant code with

```
/*= ANSWER CODE ==============================================================
...
=============================================================================*/
```

The example uses counters and changes color for 30 frames after a collision with another ball or wall.

I did not use a semaphore as all the balls would be red within a second.

```js
canvas.width = innerWidth -20;
canvas.height = innerHeight -20;
mathExt(); // creates some additional math functions
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const GRAVITY = 0;
const WALL_LOSS = 1;
const BALL_COUNT = 10;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const MIN_BALL_SIZE = 6;
const MAX_BALL_SIZE = 30;
const VEL_MIN = 1;
const VEL_MAX = 5; 
const MAX_RESOLUTION_CYCLES = 100; // Put too many balls (or too large) in the scene and the 
                                   // number of collisions per frame can grow so large that
                                   // it could block the page.

                                   // If the number of resolution steps is above this value
                                   // simulation will break and balls can pass through lines,
                                   // get trapped, or worse. LOL
const SHOW_COLLISION_TIME = 30;
const balls = [];
const lines = [];
function Line(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}
Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}
    
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;

    /*= ANSWER CODE ==============================================================*/
    this.collided = 0;
    /*============================================================================*/
}
Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += GRAVITY;
    },
    draw() {

        /*= ANSWER CODE ==============================================================*/
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.collided ? (this.collided--, "#F00") : "#00F";
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r - 1.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.stroke();
       /* ============================================================================*/


    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2,  this.r);
        if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;
        if (d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y, 
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                this.r, b.r
            );
            if (times.length) {
                if (times.length === 1) {
                    if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) { return times[0] }
                    return;
                }
                if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) { return times[0] }
                    if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { return times[1] }
                    return
                }
                if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { return times[1] }                
                if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) { return times[0] }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
    
            /*= ANSWER CODE ==============================================================*/

        this.collided = SHOW_COLLISION_TIME;
        /*============================================================================*/
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;            
        const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;   
        this.y += this.vy * time;   
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * WALL_LOSS;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * WALL_LOSS;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) { // b is second ball

        /*= ANSWER CODE ==============================================================*/

        this.collided = SHOW_COLLISION_TIME;
        b.collided = SHOW_COLLISION_TIME;
        /*============================================================================*/

        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;        
        const x = a.x - b.x
        const y = a.y - b.y  
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
    }       
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for(const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) { return false }
    }
    return true;
}
function create(bCount) {
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 20, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 30)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(30, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 30, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 
    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(VEL_MIN, VEL_MAX);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(MAX_BALL_SIZE + 30, canvas.width - MAX_BALL_SIZE - 30), 
                Math.rand(MAX_BALL_SIZE + 30, canvas.height - MAX_BALL_SIZE - 30),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(MIN_BALL_SIZE, MAX_BALL_SIZE),
            );
            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
    while (resolving && e++ < MAX_RESOLUTION_CYCLES) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;
        for (const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (const l of lines) {
                const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            idx ++;
        }
        if (resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }
            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}
create(BALL_COUNT);
mainLoop();
function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    resolveCollisions();
    for (const b of balls) { b.update() }
    for (const b of balls) { b.draw() }

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(const l of lines) { l.draw() }
    ctx.stroke();

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function mathExt() {
    Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
    Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
    Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1
    // contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h) [where (,) is coord (x,y)]
    Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => { // args (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, r1, r2)
        const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
        const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
        var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
        const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
        const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
        const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
        return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
    }   
    Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
        if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) { return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : []  }
        b /= a;
        var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);
        if (d > 0) {
            d = d ** 0.5;
            return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
        }
        return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
    }
    Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2,  r) => {
        const xx = x2 - x1;
        const yy = y2 - y1;
        const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;
        if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
            const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
            const nx = xx * dd;
            const ny = yy * dd;
            return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x -(x1 - ny))) / d;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const collided = {
  color: 'red',
  get current() {
    return this.color
  },
  set current(clr) {
    if (this.color === 'red') {
      this.color = 'blue'
    } else {
      this.color = 'red'
    }
  }
}
this.update= function(){
  for(let i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
      if(this!==circles[i] && getDistance(this.x,this.y,circles[i].x,circles[i].y)<=200*200){
          this.c=collided.current
          collided.current = this.c
          circles[i].c=collided.current
          resolveCollision(this,circles[i]);
      }
      // ...
    }
}
```

The trick is to use use getters and setters to ensure that the most recently used color value is never reapplied

Answer (score 0):

First, split the `if`:

```
  // psudo-code
  if this is not circles[i], then
    if overlapping, then
      do something
    else
      do something else
  else
    do nothing
```

Then, fix `if this is not circles[i]`:
`{x:100,y:100}!={x:100,y:100}`, so
either add `id` to circles and compare `id`s (my recommendation), or,
compare `.x`s and `.y`s (less desired - what if they are equal but not same circle?), or,
use `JSON.stringify(a)==JSON.stringify(b)`.

I would add `.overlapping` and before the loop, I'd add another loop setting all `.overlapping` to false, then, withing the modified original loop, I'd check if `.overlapping` is `false`, and then if there is a collision, I'd set `.overlapping` to true for both.
Another way would be to create an array to hole overlapping circles' `.id`s and check if that array `includes` the current loop item's `.id`.